Android - Wrong flag receiving for button obscured case in specific Redmi and OPPO models. #FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED
We using the following snippet for ensuing that no app is above my app(to prevent click hijacking). But specific redmi and oppo models always returning that my app obscured by other app.
private boolean isObscured(MotionEvent event) {
    if ((event.getFlags() & MotionEvent.FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED) != 0) {
        Log.i(“Button is being obscured");
        return true;
    }
    if ((event.getFlags() & MotionEvent.FLAG_WINDOW_IS_PARTIALLY_OBSCURED) != 0) {
        Log.i(“Button is being partially obscured");
        return true;
    }
    Log.i(“Button is not obscured");
    return false;
}

Im just confirmed that no apps above my app by,
1.removing screen-overlay permission for all apps.
2.By current activity app
Device Models:
Redmi 9
Redmi 7 pro
OPPO F15, MODEL-CPH2001
POCO M2
Im expecting it should only return obscured if a app's present above my app, such as like screen recording, screen sharing and unwanted app's activity present above app. But it's always returning obscured flag in all button click actions.
